# While sending json data in ajax gives an error like Unexpected token :

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating login with facebook application in codeigniter. So, I want to pass json data into my controller using ajax.

Here my code is like :

```
var data = JSON.stringify(response);
   alert(data);
   $.ajax(function(){
     type:"post",
     //contentType: 'application/json',
     //dataType: 'json',
     url:"<?php echo base_url().'login/insert_fb' ?>",
     data:{email:email,id:id}
   }).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
   });
```

Here, In my login controller I have written code like this :

```
function insert_fb()
{       
    $data = json_decode($this->input->post($response));
    print_r($data);
}
```

Here, In data variable i got all json record.But when I call ajax function then it gives an error like **Unexpected token :**.

So, how can I resolve this problem?

**Note :** If I remove method and dataType and contentType then it gives an error like **Unexpected token :** at **url**.

Comment: you need to use 'type' instead of 'method' to set the request verb.

Comment: Probably your PHP code has mistakes, please open console on your browser and click on error line. You'll see the exact error.

Comment: and the ajax call expects a js object, not a callback function.

Comment: I dont see $response declared any where. Where are you getting the error, in the response to ajax or when the page loads and the error shows up in the console?

Comment: @MubasharAbbas It gives an error at **dataType: 'json',** when i hover it shows **unexpected token**

Comment: @DenizB. Here is [My page link](http://104.128.224.167/job_portal/login/) where you can check it

Comment: data:{response:data,id:id} on server is $_POST['response'], $_POST['id']

Comment: @MaximColesnic I just check that if i got an array or not in my controller.

Comment: What does "data" (the array you `stringify` look like before and after?

Comment: @Nisarg you send ajax to server side and browser expect correct json as answer. Check it.

Comment: What @MaximColesnic says is true. By setting `datatype: "json"` you are saying "only accept a JSON return". Your php array is not a json return. Remove the datatype for testing purposes.

Comment: Here I have pass json data into my controller then I have to convert it into array and store into database. Thats why i have use json_decode and print those data because what data i see in an array.

Comment: @Nisarg Yes, but you are *also* returning this array, while your ajax call is expecting json in return. The `datatype` does not mean "send out JSON". It means "receive JSON back".

Comment: @Babydead Ok. So I have remove the contenttype and datatype from ajax till it gives an error.

Comment: @Nisarg Please get full code JS and PHP. And in browser development tools in network find your ajax request and see server response. Is a correct json?

Comment: @Nisarg If you remove `contenttype` and `datatype` it should not give any error at all. It should simply alert whatever the php script echoes. This could be an error, or it could be your array print.

Comment: Your page already has an error before posting any data. Please fix it first.

Comment: Just remove **function()** from ajax den its working.

Comment: Yes, that's great, good for you. Glad you've solved it. However, anyone could've guessed this if they weren't so confused because of your poorly formulated question. Next time, please make sure we know what variables you are sending where and such. Everyone was seeing possible errors but nobody could verify anything because of a lack of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `function()` from your ajax:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(response);
   alert(data);
   $.ajax({
     type:"post",
     //contentType: 'application/json',
     //dataType: 'json',
     url:"<?php echo base_url().'login/insert_fb' ?>",
     data:{email:email,id:id}
   }).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
   });
```

Comment: I have just remove function form ajax and its working.